# Sharepoint: How do I filter a document library view to show the contents of a subfolder?

Tags: sharepoint, filter, subdirectory

A number of business areas I work with use a folder structure to organise their Sharepoint housed documents (not ideal I know, but we're stuck with it).

I would like to use a web part page to present a number of views of their document libraries based on the subfolders that the documents appear in, but this is proving more difficult than I had thought.  Has anyone overcome this problem in the past?

Answer (score 21):

With Sharepoint Designer you can edit the CAML of your XSLT List View.

If you set the Scope attribute of the View element to *Recursive* or *RecursiveAll*, which returns all Files and Folders, you can filter the documents by *FileDirRef*:

```
<Where>
   <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
      <Value Type='Lookup'>MyFolder</Value>
   </Contains>
</Where>
```

This returns all documents which contain the string 'MyFolder' in their path.

I found infos about this on http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/querying-document-libraries-or-pulling-teeth-with-caml/ and useful information abouts fields at http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/03/21/wss-field-display-amp-internal-names-for-lists-amp-document-libraries.aspx

Comment: Sorry just noticed this thread is dead, but it still shows up in google so maybe someone looking for a solution stumbles upon it

Comment: The point of StackOverflow is to be a continually updated reference for questions.  This would normally be considered a necropost on other sites, but here, this kind of thing is encouraged.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Have you thought about creating a view with 'Folder =  Show all items without folders', that would get all your documents out of their folders and then perhaps you could create your filter(s) over that view.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the content by type web part - http://codeplex.com/eoffice - probably the most flexible viewing web part.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of document library information do you want in the view?
How do you want the user to filter the view?

In general the most powerful way of creating views in sharepoint is with the data view web part. 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100948041033.aspx

You will need Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer.

You can present different views of you folders using the data view filter and sorting controls.

You can use web part connections to filter a dataview.
You can use any datasource linked to say a drop down to filter a dataview.
[How to tie a dropdown list to a gridview in Sharepoint 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177076/how-to-tie-a-dropdown-list-to-a-gridview-in-sharepoint-2007)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any out-of-the-box way to achieve this. As you say, this is not how SharePoint lists are intended used.
It might work to create a custom site column displaying the path to the document, as this might be used in a filter. Have never tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Page Viewer webpart and switch from Web Page to Folder.  You can the specify the folder you want to display in the Link.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get a direct link to a view within a folder by using "TreeValue", "TreeField" and "RootFolder".

Example:

```
http://sharepoint/Docs/YourLibrary/Forms/YourView.aspx?RootFolder=MyFolder&TreeField=Folders&TreeValue=MyFolder
```

To further explain: 
I have a SharePoint site, with a docs library called YourLibrary. I have a folder called MyFolder. I created a view that can be used at any level of that Library structure with a URL path of YourView.aspx
Using that link, it will take me to the view I created, with all the filters and styles, but only show the results that would occur in the contents of that folder in RootFolder and TreeValue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pick or create one column and make that value required so that it's always populated such as title.  A field that doesn't hold the name of the folder.  Then in your filter put the filter you wanted that will select only the files you want.  Then add an or to your filter, select your "required" field then set it equal to and leave the filter blank.  Since all folders will have a blank in this required field your folders will show up with your files.

Answer (score 0):

In SP2013 Online, I tried the filter conditions as `Name` `Contains` `Folder_I_want_to_list`

This showed me all the folders containing the `Name` in their file path. It lists even sub-folder contents which wasn't available when i tried `Name` `equal to` `Folder_I_want_to_list`