# Viewing the content of a folder within a SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, document, directory

I have document library called 'Documents'. In there I have this folder structure 'Public' > 'Documents' > 'Legal'. To display the content i.e. Files and folders I can use a web-part.

But My problem is I only want to display the content of this 'Legal' folders document only not the whole document library documents.

How am I suppose to solve this matter?

Chiranthaka

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharepoint: How do I filter a document library view to show the contents of a subfolder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295448/sharepoint-how-do-i-filter-a-document-library-view-to-show-the-contents-of-a-su)

Comment: Above solution works and also I found my own one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add a field and stop it is been viewed. I put a value in that field and filter the view according to that value.